# why do we need to design a state machine to implement a playback app?

Tags: playback, state-machine

can't we just write some play() stop() pause() function instead?
what's the advantage of using a state machine to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main advantage in your case is that each state determines what actions are valid and how the state machine reacts on them.

In a very simple model your state machine would have the states

- Playing
- Pausing
- Not Playing

Each of these states defines which actions are valid. It makes no sense to allow a call to Play() in state **Playing**.
It also makes no sense to allow Stop() in state **Not Playing**.
The state machine helps you figuring out what actions are valid in which state.

By the way: Every program is kind of a state machine, but not every program is modeled after one. By creating the model your code automatically becomes more structured and readability increases.